# Конвертировать long в char array

Tags: c++

Мне нужно сконвертировать переменную типа long в char array. Как это организовать?

Comment: В каком смысле? 4 байта в 4-байтный массив? Или значение типа long в строковое представление?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <string>
const std::string str=std::to_string(my_value);
str.c_str() - нужный массив
```

Comment: Забавно. Лично я сначала воспринял вопрос как `char a[4]; memcpy(a,&l,4);`...

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос допускает неоднозначную трактовку. :-) Мой вариант ответа:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{

  long vallong=0x0102030405060708;
  char* charptr=(char*)(&vallong);

  std::cout <<std::endl<< "sizeof(long)=" << sizeof(long);
  std::cout <<std::endl<< "charptr=" << (int)charptr[0];
  std::cout <<std::endl<< "charptr=" << (int)charptr[1];
  std::cout <<std::endl<< "charptr=" << (int)charptr[2];
  std::cout <<std::endl<< "charptr=" << (int)charptr[3];
  std::cout <<std::endl<< "charptr=" << (int)charptr[4];
  std::cout <<std::endl<< "charptr=" << (int)charptr[5];
  std::cout <<std::endl<< "charptr=" << (int)charptr[6];
  std::cout <<std::endl<< "charptr=" << (int)charptr[7];


}
```

Вывод программы:

sizeof(long)=8
charptr=8
charptr=7
charptr=6
charptr=5
charptr=4
charptr=3
charptr=2
charptr=1
Exit code: 0 (normal program termination)

Проверялось на cpp.sh